# Regular expression to enforce length checks too

Tags: regex

I have the following (not working) regular expression

```
(^$|(([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?))((^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$)|(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{11})$)))
```

Let me break down the logic.

`^$|` is the first part this essentially means if the string is 0 length it validates true.

obviously | denotes an or.

then adding the next bit.

`([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)` - this is the format of the string that needs to match, in reality this to match a BIC (Bank Identifier Code).

So we end up with:

```
pattern: '(^$|([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?))'
```

Basically only match the BIC if a value was provided, good so far?

However now I want to extend this to also ensure that the string is either 8 or 11 characters.

so I came up with this little query to match 8 characters: `(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$)`

so if we bundle that in to our regex we end up with

```
'(^$|([a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$))'
```

So at this point it isn't working .

What is the correct way to do a length check ?

Is it something with the syntax causing the problem ?

Comment: Aren't you missing the OR in the regexp?

Comment: Can you give desired acceptable and unacceptable inputs ?

Comment: Don't think so should read like len(0) OR (patten AND len(8))

Comment: desired would be BIC of len 8 or 11 or no input. Undesirable would be anything else, eg: string with 9 characters.

Comment: The last regexp does not contain an OR, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Also, for the people that do not know what a BIC is, an example in the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `I want to extend this to also ensure that the string is either 8 or 11 characters.`

First your regex can be shortened to:

```
([a-zA-Z]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)
```

And if you notice you are already matching length=8 or length=11 since last 3 alpha numerics are optional. I would suggest enclose them with start/end anchors to enforce the length.

Your **final regex** can be this:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?)?$
```

**PS:** You don't really need a specific `^$` to match since I have made whole regex optional thus allowing it to match empty strings.

**Online Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lA6jK6**

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lookahead assertion to look for 8 or 11 chars, followed by the end of the string.

In PCRE and JS:

```
(^$|^(?=.{8}(?:.{3})?$)(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking string length with a regular expression? A certain Jamie Zawinski quote comes to mind. Just use string.length() (in whatever format it exists in the language you're using) and keep your regular expression simple; at this point you're just multiplying problems for yourself trying to do everything in a regex.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't always do this. Agreed if it is your own code, control or validation, but when working with validation frameworks you're often a lot more limited. So typically you end up with convenience for 95% of your validation, but there are always those remaining cases where the framework itself is limiting.